# Shell Script working with multiple files

Tags: linux, shell

I have this code below:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=$1
file_extension=$( echo $1 | cut -d. -f2 )
directory=${filename%.*}

if [[ -z $filename ]]; then
    echo "You forgot to include the file name, like this:"
    echo "./convert-pdf.sh my_document.pdf"
else
    if [[ $file_extension = 'pdf' ]]; then
        [[ ! -d $directory ]] && mkdir $directory
        convert $filename -density 300 $directory/page_%04d.jpg
    else
        echo "ERROR! You must use ONLY PDF files!"
    fi
fi
```

And it is working perfectly well!

I would like to create a script which I can do something like this: ./script.sh *.pdf

How can I do it? Using asterisk.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly realize that the shell will expand `*.pdf` to a list of arguments. This means that your shell script will never ever see the `*`. Instead it will get a list of arguments.

You can use a construction like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

function convert() {
  local filename=$1
  # do your thing here
}

if (( $# < 1 )); then
  # give your error message about missing arguments
fi
while (( $# > 0 )); do
  convert "$1"
  shift
done
```

What this does is first wrap your functionality in a function called `convert`. Then for the main code it first checks the number of arguments passed to the script, if this is less than 1 (i.e. none) you give the error that a filename should be passed. Then you go into a while loop which is executed as long as there are arguments remaining. The first argument you pass to the convert function which does what your script already does. Then the `shift` operation is performed, what this does is it throws away the first argument and then shifts all the remaining arguments "left" by one place, that is what was `$2` now is `$1`, what was `$3` now is `$2`, etc. By doing this in the while loop until the argument list is empty you go through all the arguments.

By the way, your initial assignments have a few issues:

- you can't assume that the filename has an extension, your code could match a dot in some directory path instead.
- your directory assignment seems to be splitting on . instead of /
- your directory assignment will contain the filename if no absolute or relative path was given, i.e. only a bare filename
- ...

I think you should spend a bit more time on robustness

Comment: `convert "$1"`, not `convert($1)`. And avoid the `function` keyword -- it makes code incompatible with POSIX-baseline shells for no good reason (unlike bashisms, like `(( ))`, that actually add value).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, using too many languages at once it seems... corrected the function call. I don't really agree about the function keyword, it makes it much clearer to people no so familiar with shell script that a function is being defined and since it is an actual bash script anyway the incompatibility is a moot point. I should make clear that it is a bash script however, I'll add the appropriate hashbang.

Comment: btw, the point of using `:` instead of `#` for placeholders is that it leaves your code syntactically valid even if nobody fills in the placeholder. With just the comment in the body of a conditional or loop it won't parse.

Comment: Re: the `function` keyword, choosing to use it in examples makes the portable syntax being less-frequently recognized amongst newcomers a self-fulfilling prophecy.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a loop. That is, instead of:

```
filename=$1
: code goes here
```

use:

```
for filename in "$@"; do
  : put your code here
done
```

Comment: Community wiki to avoid harvesting rep from answering a known duplicate